# Unity 3D Find Object By Tag Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have gameobject with tag "Player" assigned to it and try to find it via С# script:

```
private GameObject player1;

void Srart(){

   player1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
   if (player1 == null)
      Debug.LogError ("Object with player tag had not been found!");
}

void Update(){

    Debug.Log (player1.name);
}
```

The problem is that NullReferenceException is thrown in Update() function, but LogError message is not. That means that my object was succesfully found by tag. But somehow it wasn't, because player1 in update function is equal to null. So why do i have this error?

Comment: Are you sure 'player1.name' is not null. Should check with String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(player1.name), if I am getting your question right

Comment: That's not the problem - player1 is equal to null in Update() but somehow checking in start() function doesn't see it. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error.

Change `void Srart()` to `void Start()`.

Check out http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html and other MonoBehaviour methods -- spelling is crucial!